# Auto value generation for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I am a NodeJS backend Dev, started learning spring boot, I was just wandering if it's possible to generate a field value with existing values for different field.

let me clear my request. Let's suppose its my model,

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "userName", updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "userNameToLower", updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private String userNameToLower;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserNameToLower() {
        return userNameToLower;
    }

    public void setUserNameToLower(String userNameToLower) {
        this.userNameToLower = userNameToLower;
    }
}
```

On basis of `userName`(will be taken from request body, can I generate `userNameToLower` at the time of pushing it to DB, without coding it explicitly on controller.

please let me know. It will be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want to code this in the controller (or service)? When it is done in a controller- (or service-) method, it is obvious (as in: has a lower cognitive complexity), easy to find and testable.

Comment: Well, when I use mongoose we can use `.pre() ` that actually does this kind of thing, I was just trying to relate? If possible. 

Comment: There is something similiar in JPA, called [JPA entity lifecycle hooks (`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events). For the use case described, we most probably want to use `@PrePersist` (and possibly `@PreUpdate`). But again: I think that a dedicated method in a service is "cleaner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations to set up  methods that are invoked before an entity is saved or updated. Use `@EntityListeners` if you want to move the logic to a separate class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class UserModel {
  // ...

  @PrePersist
  private void prePersist() {

    // simple example without null check, etc
    username = username.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Some examples:

- https://nullbeans.com/how-to-use-prepersist-and-preupdate-in-jpa-hibernate/
- https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-audit-entity-modifications-using-the-jpa-entitylisteners-embedded-and-embeddable-annotations/

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate, there is way. Try below:

```
@Column(name = "userName")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "LOWER(userName)")
private String userName;
```